# Domain of $\frac{1}{x^{-1}}$

Tags: exponentiation, wolfram-alpha

Why WolframAlpha and other online calculators compute $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ (and not $\mathbb{R}$) as the domain of $\frac{1}{x^{-1}}$?

Since $\frac{1}{x^{-1}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$, is not the domain $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If your function is "reciprocate your argument, then do it again", then your argument must be nonzero.

Comment: Call $g:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R$, $g(x)=x^{-1}$ and $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=\frac1x$. I assume there is no complaint on the fact that $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is the domain of both $f$ and $g$, in the sense that I have not witheld artificially points in my definition. Writing $\frac1{x^{-1}}$ **means** that you want $f(g(x))$ (because I said so and because the board of education backs me up), so you want $\operatorname{dom}(f\circ g)=\{x\in\operatorname{dom}g\,:\, g(x)\in\operatorname{dom}f\}=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: What is $\frac 1 x$ in your expression $\frac 1 {x^{-1}} = \frac 1 {\frac 1 x}$ for $x = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like your argument. But the truth is, you could only make the simplification when $x$ is in the domain of $f(x)=\frac1x$ and of course $f(f(x))$. In this case, $f(0)$ doesn't exist, so the domain of $f(f(x))$ doesn't include $0$.

However, we do have that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(f(x))=0$$Because we could substitute $x=0$ after simplification.

Answer (score 2):

As noticed it is absolutely true that

$$\frac{1}{x^{-1}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}}=x$$

and also that the domain for $x$ is $\mathbb{R}$ but your original expression is not defined at $x=0$ therefore its domain is exactly $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.

In other words the two expressions are completely equivalent but only for $x\neq 0$.

This kind of discontinuity is defined as a removable one since we can set the value at $x=0$ for $\frac{1}{x^{-1}}$ equal to zero and in this way its domain becomes $\mathbb{R}$.